# Javascript ES6 calling a method inside another method within the same class shows an error the class i am calling is undefined

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I am using Javascript ES6 classes. I have created a Player class as below:

```
class Player {

  constructor() {
     .....
     .....
  }
  changeShipDirection(shipName, direction) {
    let redraw = false;
    this.ships.filter(function(ship) {
        if (ship.name === shipName) {
            ship.direction = direction;
            if (ship.location.length > 0) {
                redraw = true;
                let coordinates = this.getCoordinatesOfShip(ship.name);
            }
        }
     });

     return redraw
   }

   getCoordinatesOfShip(shipName) {
      let coordinates = [];
      this.ships.filter(function(ship) {
          if (ship.name === shipName) {
              coordinates = ship.location;
          }
      });

      return coordinates;
   }

}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'getCoordinatesOfShip' of undefined

I have cases where I use the same technique i.e. calling a method within the class and it works.

Comment: You should use `some` and `find` instead of `filter`. Also, what do you need those `coordinates` variable for if you don't use it at all?

Answer (score 7):

That's because `this` inside that function you passed to filter is not bound to the class. There are multiple ways to fix it.

One is to use arrow function which retains the `this` binding of the scope it's defined in

```
this.ships.filter((ship) => {
        if (ship.name === shipName) {
            ship.direction = direction;
            if (ship.location.length > 0) {
                redraw = true;
                let coordinates = this.getCoordinatesOfShip(ship.name);
            }
        }
     });
```

Another can be to first retain the `this` reference for the outer function in some other variable and then use that inside the function passed to filter -

```
var self = this
this.ships.filter(function(ship) {
        if (ship.name === shipName) {
            ship.direction = direction;
            if (ship.location.length > 0) {
                redraw = true;
                let coordinates = self.getCoordinatesOfShip(ship.name);
            }
        }
     });
```

Yet another way is to bind that function to the `this` bound to the outer function -

```
this.ships.filter(function(ship) {
        if (ship.name === shipName) {
            ship.direction = direction;
            if (ship.location.length > 0) {
                redraw = true;
                let coordinates = this.getCoordinatesOfShip(ship.name);
            }
        }
     }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Did you try all the 3 ways :)

Comment: I just tried the third way.. i already had tried to bind this but in an incorrect way so after I saw your answer i used your way :)

Comment: @MukeshSoni Which do you think is the best programming practice ?

Comment: @SandipSubedi It's a matter of taste but i personally prefer the arrow functions (the first approach). It's cleaner and also has scope for compiler optimizations.